# how can I wait(hold ) my execution untill a element is present and once its gone I should move ahead in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
WebElement inProgress = Util.getElementByXPath(driver,
    Constants.XPATH.HOME_PAGE.COMPANY_MENU_ADMIN.BATCH_SCHEDULING_LIST.INPROGRESS1);
if (inProgress != null) {
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    while (inProgress != null && inProgress.isDisplayed()) {
        inProgress = Util.getElementByXPath(driver,
            Constants.XPATH.HOME_PAGE.COMPANY_MENU_ADMIN.BATCH_SCHEDULING_LIST.INPROGRESS1);
        clickRefreshButton();
    }
}
```

Above is the code what I have written, sometimes it works and sometimes throws exception

Comment: Try using explicit wait with condition `visibilityOfElementLocated` and then `invisibilityOfElementLocated` before proceeding with remaining steps.

Comment: can you write it and integrate it with above mentioned code. That would b great help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-inventing the wheel and implementing your custom approach to wait until element is present go for [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) and [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) classes combination like:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10)
        .until(ExpectedConditions
                .invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.
                        xpath(Constants
                                .XPATH
                                .HOME_PAGE
                                .COMPANY_MENU_ADMIN
                                .BATCH_SCHEDULING_LIST
                                .INPROGRESS1)));
```

More information: [WebDriver Advanced Usage: Explicit Waits](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)

Or even better you can refactor your code to use [Page Object Model Design Pattern](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model), this way you will not have to define any "waits" as elements will be automatically searches on first access given - [PageFactory](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) will handle all the stuff under the hood.